# Modify Marketing Cloud default UI

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have a requirement wherein I have to add a custom button next to the browse button as shown in the screenshot.

This button will redirect to a new URL and do the further processing.

Is it possible to do this or is there any documentation to that disapproves that the following requirement cannot be achieved.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will recommend you to look into Content Builder SDK, to create your own components, with custom integrations. There is some documentation on it [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/content-sdk.htm), along with a link to the SDK on GitHub

This way, you will be able to add your own features to blocks, which your marketers will drag into emails and reuse.

Comment: Thank You. But can I make changes to the existing UI and create a button alongside the browse button that uploads the images in content builder

Comment: Unfortunately you can’t change existing components. But you can build a new one, with similar features and add your own requirements “on top”. Not saying it’s easy, but it’s possible.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this isn't possible at the moment.

Marketing Cloud UI is locked down for the most part, the only ways to have something custom is to create a custom app for Marketing Cloud which comes with new features / buttons, though I don't think you can customize existing layouts (*ex* ContentBuilder)

For visual adjustments (colors/logo) there's the Brand Builder.

There's the option to add Custom Tabs for Tracking as well, though that's it for customizability.

Comment: Is there any document from salesforce that mentions that it is not possible? that would be of a great help.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't covered in official documentation, but it has been asked a couple of times in the Marketing Cloud Community Group. Darryl Brown from Salesforce is the person you can confirm this with.

Comment: Thanks, @rain for your inputs. it certainly cleared my doubts.